# Adding parallax effect to background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working creating a parallax effect. I have an image and a background color. Based on the scroll this background color must move top and when scroll back to 0, it should move to its actual position.

At the moment, when I scroll this color moves directly to top and when scroll position moves back to 0, it does not come down.

```js
function parallax() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 0.5) + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false)
```

```css
body {
  background: cyan;
}

#image {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 310px;
  right: -30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.frst {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
<div class='div1' style=" position:relative;width: 50%; height: 350px; background-color: red; top: 20%;">
  <div id='image'></div>
</div>
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Aside from the issue, having multiple elements with the same `id`, `#frst` in your case, is invalid. You need to make them unique, or remove them as they serve no purpose.

Comment: not sure what colors are you talking about for each case. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @EliyaCohen I am trying to add effect on that green color rectangle `<div id='image'></div>` Sorry for the naming convention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you didn't remove the `top` rule when it comes back to zero:

```
if (image.style.top === "0px") {
  image.style.top = "";
}
```

This demo will work, but that's just a "bandage". I would suggest using an initial top instead.

```js
function parallax() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image');
  image.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 0.5) + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false)
```

```css
body {
  background: cyan;
}

#image {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  right: -30px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(310px);
}

.frst {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
<div class='div1' style=" position:relative;width: 50%; height: 350px; background-color: red; top: 20%;">
  <div id='image'></div>
</div>
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
<div class='frst'>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br> hhvvv  <br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>hhvvv<br>
</div>
```

Comment: And when I scroll, it is directly going to top. I need it to slowly move to top

Comment: Then you need to use an initial top. Since CSS can't animate from an unset top to a specific top.

Comment: How to set initial top?

Comment: I set the initial top to zero and then used transform translateY to 310px. Look now.